# Excel 2013 I have defined names, but I need to access the names from string concatenation. Is it possible?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel 2013, I have defined names for the range of cells.

but in the formula I need to access the defined names from string concatenation.

Ex. Defined name : B2: B10  as March_Sales

Formular : =sum("March"&"_Sales") - Its possible. Can anyone please help me

Comment: does =sum(indirect("March"&"_Sales")) work?

Answer (score 0):

The following all work:

```
=SUM(March_Sales)
=SUM(INDIRECT("March_Sales"))
=SUM(INDIRECT("Mar" & "ch_" & "Sal" & "es"))
```